# How do I delete messages fter they have been sent on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm running into a problem where I'm trying to delete a message if a certain variable is 1.

```
class vars:
    locked = 1

@client.event
async def on_messge(message):
if vars.locked == 1:
    await message.delete()
```

I tried it with an alt account (which has no permissions) and still doesn't work. Any help accepted! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to have any issues other than indentation error (which should have thrown you a `SyntaxError` in the first place)

I rewrote the code and it didn't have any problem and worked exactly according to the description.

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot()


class vars:
    locked = 1


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {client.user}")


@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if vars.locked == 1:
        await msg.delete()


client.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Since I couldn't demonstrate it working (because deleted messages are deleted) I made this example :

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == client.user:
        return
    if vars.locked == 1:
        await msg.channel.send(
            f"Deleted the msg **{msg.content}** because vars.locked = {vars.locked}"
        )
        await msg.delete()
```

Which resulted in :

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that.